# Swift sprite kit vertical background infinite image

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have 3 images:

`topBg.png`
`midBg.png`
`botBg.png`

I want to set `topBg.png` at top scene and height = 200

`middleBg.png` should be infinite scale or repeat vertically

`botBg.png` - should be in bottom and height = 200

i have next code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.bgTopSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "//bgTopNode") as? SKSpriteNode
        self.bgMiddleSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "//bgMiddleNode") as? SKSpriteNode
        self.bgBottomSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "//bgBottomNode") as? SKSpriteNode

        if let bgTopSpriteNode = self.bgTopSpriteNode,
            let bgMiddleSpriteNode = self.bgMiddleSpriteNode,
            let bgBottomSpriteNode = self.bgBottomSpriteNode {



            bgTopSpriteNode.size.width = self.frame.width
            bgTopSpriteNode.size.height = 200
            bgTopSpriteNode.position.x = 0

            bgMiddleSpriteNode.size.width = self.frame.width
            bgMiddleSpriteNode.size.height = self.frame.height-400
            bgMiddleSpriteNode.position.x = 0

            bgBottomSpriteNode.size.width = self.frame.width
            bgBottomSpriteNode.size.height = 200
            bgBottomSpriteNode.position.x = 0
        }

    }
```

But how to set `Y` position of images. Because coordinates begin from center of screen, not from left top and i don't know how to convert them.

Comment: You can give more informations about this code as for example the scaleMode adopted to your scene..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano what does this mean? i want to fit in different sizes: ipad iphone.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano this is image that i cut into 3 pieces: http://storage6.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1006/h_1475759533_7324679_c41559f9fd.png

Comment: theoretically, this might be possible in the scene editor, by putting a stretch to bounds/edges constraint on your middle texture. But I haven't tried it.

Comment: Arli, this is a good reason to use SKTileMapNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to achieve what you're looking to do.

- First, you can compute the y position of the top and the bottom of the screen using simply size.height / 2 if you have the anchorPoint of your scene at (0.5,0.5).  (Don't use frame - use size.  That way, you take into account the scaleMode of the scene.)
- It sounds like you are frustrated that the origin of the scene is in the center.  If you'd like to move it to the corner, you can easily do so by setting the scene's anchorPoint property, say, to (0.0, 0.0) for the lower left corner.  Then, your y-values are 0 and size.height.  If you are using the .sks editor, this is exposed in the interface - you can just set it there.  Otherwise, you can set it programmatically.
- Finally, you can set the scaleMode of your scene to something like .aspectFill, set the size of the scene directly (say, to 1024x768 for an iPad), and just place the images wherever they need to go.  This approach works particularly well with .sks files, if you are using them; when you load up a scene, you can set the size of the scene based on the aspect ratio of the view it's in to accommodate different aspect ratios.  For instance, you could adopt a 320x480 "reference size" for your iPhone scenes.  Whenever you load up the scene, you could set the size of the scene to be 320 points wide and however many points tall to match the aspect ratio of the device.  Then, all your graphics would be produced at 320pt wide, and you could slide them up or down proportionally across the scene's size for layout.  This is a little more complicated, but it's a lot easier than trying to deal with separate layout considerations for multiple devices.

I should also point out a couple of things.

- You can use the anchorPoint property of a sprite to dictate where the sprite's coordinates are measured from.  This is handy for cases where you want images to be flush up against something.  For instance, if you want an image flush against the left side of the screen, set its position to be exactly the left side of the screen, and then set its anchorPoint.x to 0.0; this will put the left edge of the sprite against the left edge of the screen.  This also works for scenes, as you encountered - moving the anchorPoint of the scene moves everything in the scene relative to its size.
- You don't need three images for what you're describing.  You can use a single sprite and just set its centerRect property to tell it to use the top and bottom of an image and stretch the center part vertically.  You have to do a little math to set the right xScale and yScale (*not* width and height, IIRC), but then you can draw all of that with one sprite instead of three.  This would be really handy in your case, because you could just leave the sprite at (0,0), set its scale to match the size of the entire scene, and set the centerRect property - you wouldn't have to do any positioning math at all.